# Laravel Eloquent compare date from datetime field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, laravel-4

I want to get all the rows from a table through an expression:

```
table.date <= 2014-07-10
```

But if the column contains a datetime let's say:

```
2014-07-10 12:00:00
```

But if I do:

```
where('date', '<=', $date)
```

it won't get the row.

I guess this is because $date = 2014-07-10 which makes MySQL assume that it is 2014-07-10 00:00:00.

In regular MySQL I would just do

```
where DATE(date) <= $date
```

What would be the equivalent using Laravel's Eloquent?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Laravel 4+ offers you these methods: `whereDay()`, `whereMonth()`, `whereYear()` ([#3946](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/3946)) and `whereDate()` ([#6879](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/6879)).

They do the SQL `DATE()` work for you, and manage the differences of SQLite.

Your result can be achieved as so:

```
->whereDate('date', '<=', '2014-07-10')
```

For more examples, see first message of [#3946](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/3946) and this [Laravel Daily article](http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/).

**Update:** Though the above method is convenient, as noted by Arth it is inefficient on large datasets, because the `DATE()` SQL function has to be applied on each record, thus discarding the possible index.

Here are some ways to make the comparison (but please read notes below):

```
->where('date', '<=', '2014-07-10 23:59:59')

->where('date', '<', '2014-07-11')

// '2014-07-11'
$dayAfter = (new DateTime('2014-07-10'))->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d');

->where('date', '<', $dayAfter)
```

Notes:

- 23:59:59 is okay (for now) because of the 1-second precision, but have a look at this article: [23:59:59 is not the end of the day. No, really!](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/235959-is-not-the-end-of-the-day-no-really)
- Keep in mind the "zero date" case ("0000-00-00 00:00:00"). Though, these "zero dates" should be avoided, they are source of so many problems. Better make the field nullable if needed.

Comment: Again, I would advise against this method, it wraps the column in the `DATE()` function and the engine cannot use an index on the column.

Comment: No problem! I was wrong about dates being compared like strings, they just get converted and then compared. `2014-07-11` will be implicitly converted to `2014-07-11 00:00:00` before comparison, which fortunately holds up well with your other explanations.

Comment: Also note that instead of mucking around with the date in PHP, you can happily use `WHERE date < :date + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: Indeed about the MySQL `INTERVAL`. Though, when possible, I prefer doing processings the PHP side rather than MySQL or even Apache. I got tired of all their subtleties to manage.

Comment: THAX ALOT : where works for me i am using laravel 7+

Answer (score 9):

Have you considered using:

```
where('date', '<', '2014-08-11')
```

You should avoid using the `DATE()` function on indexed columns in MySQL, as this prevents the engine from using the index.

**UPDATE**

As there seems to be some disagreement about the importance of `DATE()` and indexes, I have created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/686de/3) that demonstrates the difference, see `POSSIBLE KEYS`.

Comment: Why he should avoid using `DATE()` on indexed colums?

Comment: This could be a solution but seems more like a hack than best practice. What if a filed realy contains 00:00:00 as time.

Comment: @almo, Once you get used to how MySQL compares dates it isn't too bad. It is like string comparison; '2014-08-10 00:00:00' is greater than '2014-08-10'.

Comment: @Almo You should avoid using DATE() on a indexed column because it prevents MySQL to use this index. If possible use expressions on the right side of a comparison operator. And no, this is best practice not a hack!

Comment: @VMai, you referenced the wrong commenter, but cheers for the explanation.

Comment: `::whereRaw("DATE(date) <= '2014-08-10'")`. @Arth He didn't mentioned indexes, so I don't know what's the fuzz about it. @almo `2014-07-10` will be casted to `DATETIME` (`2014-07-10 00:00:00`) like you said. However, you're comparing a `DATE` against a `DATETIME`, you either cast the `DATETIME` to `DATE` or add `23:59:59` to `$date`.

Comment: @Ben It is unusual to have a date column that isn't indexed, as it is often used for filtering, as in this very qu, or ordering. On anything other than a small table you will get a substantial performance hit by wrapping an indexed field in a function. I think it is important to point this out when answering questions, and I only included it at the end of the answer as an observation.. and then someone asked about it. Not much fuzz in my opinion.

Comment: @almo it appears I was incorrect about the comparison, see update.

Comment: Any transformation of an indexed column value in a `WHERE` condition will prevent such index from being used, so the best practice is not so much about `DATE` function itself.

Answer (score 7):

**You can get the all record of the date '2016-07-14' or before '2016-07-14' by choosing one syntax from follows:**

```
->whereDate('date','=','2014-07-10')

->whereDate('date', '<=', '2014-07-10')
```

**Or use the another code for dynamic date**

```
whereDate('date',$date)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question at all.

Comment: @SteveFromAccounting In which case, the code is not working for Laravel ? 
Can you send the code snippets?

Answer (score 4):

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

public function scopePublished($query)
{
  $now = Carbon::now();
  $date = Carbon::parse($now)->toDateString();
  $time = Carbon::parse($now)->toTimeString();
  return $query->whereDate('published_at', '<', $date)
  ->orWhere(function($query) use ($date, $time) {
    $query->whereDate('published_at', '=', $date)
    ->whereTime('published_at', '<=', $time);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
whereDate('date', '=', $date)
```

If you give whereDate then compare only date from datetime field.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still wondering how to solve it.

I use

`protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'aired'];`

In my model and in my where i do

`where('aired', '>=', time());`

So just use the unix to compare in where.

In views on the other hand you have to use the date object.

Comment: this is the only one worked for me, because I have defined in $dates :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is my logic:
if you are comparing date then your method should be whereDate and if your comparing complete datetime then your method will be only where:

```
$calendar_alert = DB::table('calendar_alerts')->whereDate('when', '=', now()->format('Y-m-d'))->where('when', '>', now()->format('H:i:s'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue, I suggest to read this article : https://dev.to/nicolus/how-to-properly-retrieve-laravel-models-between-two-dates-1bek

Note that the statement :

> The issue here is that our created_at column is usually a Datetime, so it's not a simple date but it also has a time. Which means that in practice any post created on the 30th won't be retrieved because their creation date will always be greater than 2021-06-30 (which SQL will assume means '2021-06-30 00:00:00').

... from the article isn't completly true because on my side I tested a direct comparison between a mysql "date" typed field and a string formatted like "2022-10-18", and the issue was the same, the "<=" didn't work right.