# Laravel - where less/greater than date syntax

Tags: php, laravel

This is not showing the correct count. What is the correct syntax ?

```
$this->data['Tasks'] = \DB::table('tb_tasks')->where('Status', 'like', 'Open%')->whereDate('DeadLine', '>', 'CURDATE()')->count();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent compare date from datetime field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139948/laravel-eloquent-compare-date-from-datetime-field)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use a Carbon instance:

```
$this->data['Tasks'] = \DB::table('tb_tasks')->where('Status', 'like', 'Open%')->whereDate('DeadLine', '>', Carbon::now())->count();
```

You can also use the `now()` helper

```
$this->data['Tasks'] = \DB::table('tb_tasks')->where('Status', 'like', 'Open%')->whereDate('DeadLine', '>', now())->count();
```

Comment: Thanks, `whereDate()` solved my problem.

Answer (score 19):

Use [**`DB::raw`**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions):

```
->where('datefield', '>', \DB::raw('NOW()'))
```

Answer (score 10):

We can also try this one. It works for me.

```
    $date = "2020-04-10";

    /* 
    Assumimng DB `login_date` datetime format is "Y-m-d H:i:s"
    */

    $from_date = $date.' 00:00:01';

    ->where('login_date', '>=', $from_date);
```

> By adding Where Clause in the query, we can find the result having
>   rows after the particular date.

## Option-2:

```
$date = "2020-03-25";    // Format: date('Y-m-d);

$orders = DB::table('orders')
               ->select('*')
               ->whereDate('order_datetime', '<=', $date)
               ->get();

// Here, Table Field "order_datetime", type is "datetime" 
// Assuming DB `order_datetime` stores value format like: "Y-m-d H:i:s"
```

Comment: If any query or suggestion plz comment.

Comment: Please update the answer to make sure that it has relatable content from the question (maybe modify the code provided with your implementation?) and the use of variable `$from_date` is not explained, which makes it hard to understand.

Comment: No need to enclose date  by adding  ' or " when date stored in variable

Comment: what should i do when i compare datetime on both side

Comment: @dhruvinprajapati you can add `whereBetween` OR  `where('reservation_from', '>=', $now)->where('reservation_from', '<=', $to)`

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of `whereDate` like below:

```
$query->whereDate('DeadLine', '>', Carbon::now())->count();
```