# Laravel Eloquent having trouble comparing dates in query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this query for Eloquent and for some reason it seems to be ignoring my last statement about only return dates that equal or greater then that date given.

`$searchCriteriaArray` is the array the key words I am search based on(this works)

`$searchDate is the` date I am filtering on (this does not work)

here is my query

```
$pool =User::select('id', 'email', 'updated_at', 'phone_number', 'headline','summary')
                    ->where(function ($query) use ($searchCriteriaArray){
                        for($i =0; $i < count($searchCriteriaArray); $i++){
                            $query->orwhere('headline', 'like', '%' . $searchCriteriaArray[$i] . '%' );
                        }
                    })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($searchCriteriaArray){
                        for($i =0; $i < count($searchCriteriaArray); $i++){
                            $query->orwhere('summary', 'like', '%' . $searchCriteriaArray[$i] . '%' );
                        }
                    })->where('updated_at', '>= ',$searchDate)
                    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                    ->paginate(50);
```

I have looked as some other posts, including [Laravel Eloquent compare date from datetime field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139948/laravel-eloquent-compare-date-from-datetime-field).  However this has not solved my problem.  Why is Eloquent ignoring my last where statement and how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you double check what `$searchDate` actually holds?

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted the answer and then deleted it.
I needed to add this line

```
 ->where(function ($query) use ($searchDate){
                        $query->orwhere('updated_at', '>=', $searchDate);
                    })
```