# Laravel Eloquent compare dates by specific format

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-5, eloquent

I am having a little trouble comparing dates in Laravel, where the date is a specific format.
The field in the database has the date like this `d-m-Y(20-04-2018)` and I am trying to get a result where this date is greater than the date now using this.

```
$check= Usersubstitutions::where([
   ['user_id', '=', $request->user],
   ['date_to', '>=', date("d-m-Y")]
])->first();
```

And it never works. I var dumped to see what compares, using a foreach and it says that 20-05-2018 is NOT greater than 04-04-2018.

Comment: Is the date a `DATE` field, or something else (like `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`)?

Comment: It is a varchar @ThomasEdwards

Comment: That’s going to very slow and unreliable. You should always store your dates as `DATE`s, or as `TIMESTAMP`s in some cases. That’s the easiest and fastest way for MySQL to understand them, and to allow you to compare them. There’s no need for you to store them any other way. If you want to always use them in your app the same way, use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on the model.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I just have to figure out a way to store the date as the format I listed above, because that's how the client wants it and that's how the JS plugins shows and sends it to the the backend. @ThomasEdwards

Comment: 1. It doesn’t matter what the client wants, you’re the engineer. 2. It doesn’t matter what the JS plugin, the frontend developer, or anybody else for that matter, wants. Store the date in the most logical, reliable, testable way, and then build a structured reliable way to return it to them. JavaScript isn’t reading straight from the DB. You have Laravel accessors and resources to help you manage this problem, so make sure you use them! Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your column to a date format, such as `DATE`, and then it will work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Since your field is a varchar try to cast it first to DATE then compare it with `date('d-m-Y')` like :

```
$check= Usersubstitutions::where('user_id', $request->user)
    ->where(DB::raw("DATE(date_to) >= '".date('d-m-Y')."'"))
    ->first();
```

**NOTE :** It will be better to convert the field type in your database to 'DATE'.

Comment: I would argue that this is an anti-pattern. I’m not going to downvote this answer, but I would consider this to be a ‘hack’ and I think is worth a warning to future readers of this question.

Answer (score 0):

On Laravel 4+ you may use

```
->whereDate('date_to', '>=', date("d-m-Y")
```

For more examples, see first message of [#3946](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/3946) and this [Laravel Daily](http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/) article.

but you may also use the ->where() as its more convenient.

Try this:

```
$dayAfter = (new date()->modify('+1 day')->format('d-m-Y');

->where('date_to', '>=', $dayAfter)
```

Hope it helps. if not view this [qn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139948/laravel-eloquent-compare-date-from-datetime-field) for further explanations

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be storing a DATE in a varchar field. That's not a good idea. You need to either re-create the table and store `date_to` as a date using the standard SQL `DATE` format (and use the format `Y-m-d` when inserting) or cast the column to a date when selecting:

```
$check= Usersubstitutions::where([
  ['user_id', '=', $request->user],
  [\DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(date_to,'%d-%m-%Y')")  ', '>=', date("Y-m-d")]
])->first();
```

Note this will make any indexes useless and will make the query run very very (very) slowly.

Note: `STR_TO_TIME` is MySQL only but there are equivalents in other DBMSs e.g. in SQL Server it seems to be `CONVERT(DATE, date_to, 105)`