# whereDate issue with laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to where on a date column

```
whereDate('colum1', '>', $date)
```

but it throws an error

> Illegal operator and value combination.

I'm using laravel 5.5

Comment: I think you need to use ```>=```

Comment: I believe this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846061/laravel-5-5-wheredate-wheretime-not-add-quotation/57874306

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
->whereDate('created_at', '<=', '2019-03-08');
```

Check [Laravel eloquent wheredate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139948/laravel-eloquent-compare-date-from-datetime-field)

Comment: Why would OP want to use `less than or equal to`, when they clearly state they want `greater than`.