# Laravel 5.5 whereDate/whereTime not add quotation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```php
Appointment::whereDate('schedule_date', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->whereTime('time_from', ' <= ', date('H:i:s'))
    ->whereTime('time_to', ' <= ', date('H:i:s', strtotime('+1 hour')))
    ->get();
```

When this code is running on the production server, there's no response. Perhaps it's for quotation? But how can I add this? I mean quotation (single/double).

Comment: `there's no response` - do you mean there are no results?  The obvious question - *are* there results if you check the DB?  Maybe your production server has a different timezone?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a possible bug in laravel not enclosing the date in quotes, this results in it treating the Y-m-d as a maths operation.

`whereDate('schedule_date', '=', date('Y-m-d'))`

becomes

`schedule_date = 2019-09-10`

becomes

`schedule_date = 2006`