# How to get data from database using date?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I want to selecting and showing data based on current date. I have made query selected for this, but it not working

this is my date data on table :

[image: a busy cat]

this is my query:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');
$trans = FA_transaction::where('assign_date', $now)->get();
```

when i execute the query, i don't get any data

Comment: what is the assign_date attribute date type? DateTime

Comment: @HaiderAli yes, it using Datetime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent compare date from datetime field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139948/laravel-eloquent-compare-date-from-datetime-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
$trans = FA_transaction::whereDate('date', Carbon::today())->get();
```

OR  if you want to use MySQL's CURDATE function, you can do :

```
$trans = FA_transaction::->whereRaw('Date(date) = CURDATE()')->get();
```

Comment: hello @MihirBhende, when i add `where('worker_id', $getWorker->id)` like this
`$trans = FA_transaction::where('worker_id', $getWorker->id)
                                 ->whereDate('assign_date', Carbon::today())
                                 ->get();`
I don't get any data also

Comment: Does it contain any data for the particular selection. Also do you have timezones in your system?

Comment: thanks @MihirBhende, i found my mistake, and it working now

Answer (score 1):

You can use whereDate function to filter out records based on date try this!

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');
$trans = FA_transaction:: whereDate('date','=',$now)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it

```
 $now = Carbon::today();
 $trans = FA_transaction::where('assign_date', $now)->get();
```

OR

```
 $now = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
 $trans = FA_transaction::where('assign_date', $now)->get();
```

Comment: hello, i have tried your code and work. and i have another select data with different query like this 
`$trans = FA_transaction::where('worker_id', $getWorker->id)
                                 ->whereDate('assign_date', Carbon::today())
                                 ->get();`

when i execute it, i don't got any data also

Comment: is it showing any error or empty?if it showing empty then check your input 1st

Comment: please share the full table